# Ctrl-Z equivalent for GUI Programs?

Tags: suspend, signal

I often have to run the update manager on a slow connection, and while reading my emails, I meanwhile would like to surf for 2 minutes in the web, then have the full bandwidth again for the update manager.

From the command line, I can suspend a running process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, aka suspend. But if I didn't start the program from the shell - can I do it with some signal and the `kill` command?

I read the man page for `signal` (`man -a signal`), but there I didn't find a SIGSUSPEND, only SIGSTOP, SIGTERM, SIGINT and such - which is appropriate, or is there none?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the general case you can stop (suspend a process or process group as below):

Control-Z is
`kill pidnumber -SIGSTOP`
to continue:
`kill pidnumber -SIGCONT`

Alternatively, to suspend an entire process group:
`kill -groupnumber -SIGSTOP`
and
`kill -groupnumber -SIGCONT`

Of course if you suspend a process with some element that is timed, it may not continue properly. In the use case mentioned, the repository server is timing data transfer acknowledgments, it can time-out the transfer because your client has 'gone away' or slow it down because there is 'network congestion'.

I certainly wouldn't suspend update-manager while it was updating my packages, either.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I had never tried this before, but it sure works for me. From a signal point of view control-Z _"stops"_ a process.

Comment: Thanks. It deactivates the window, but the download seems unaffected - it's continuing in the background, so I don't solve the underlying problem, but it will be useful in other situations.

Comment: I'm not sure it is, generally speaking, a good idea to suspend update-manager anyway. I don't think you want to run a system for an extended time with packages half-installed. If you cancel during the cache update or package download and start it back up soon after it will start close to where it left off.

Comment: The update manager has a cancel button, so you can cancel the progress altoghether, but it doesn't remember which package you selected. For instance the 3 biggest packages which are downloaded, where I interrupted the process are adobe acrobat, which I only use sometimes to veryfy self produced PDFs for a client, who will read them on Windows clients with adobe software, so I'm surely not vulnerable to these PDFs. Second: Kernel source, which I hadn't a look into for years, and opera, which I only use to compare self produced html to output in firefox. When the packages aren't completl down-

Comment: -loaded, they aren't installed. There is no half-installed, since I only want to interrupt the download, before installation starts. But a 60 MB download can take several hours - I don't want to lose the time, if already 20 MB where downloaded in 2 hours.

Comment: I think package downloads should be mostly restartable. Not so apt-get update after running more than 30 minutes.